# Exporting point layer from QGIS to CSV file

Tags: qgis, csv, gpx

I have saved waypoints from my Garmin as gpx and have successfully imported them into QGIS.

Is there a way to now export the layers into a csv file with coordinates?

I've tried the export to csv but that does not give me the coordinates.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Two methods are described in other answers here:

1. Save as CSV and in OGR Creation Options/Layers type "GEOMETRY=AS_XY": [Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer)
2. Create two calculated fields having the coordinates, then save as CSV: [How do I calculate the latitude and longitude of points using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)