# find polygon corner coordinates

Tags: qgis, polygon, attribute-table

I am trying to get the coordinates of each node of the polygon I create. I would like the attribute table to display the name of the polygon (ex. address) and then the coordinates of the nodes (ex. nodeA= Ax and Ay, NodeB Bx and By, NodeC Cx and Cy, NodeD Dx and Dy) is there a easy way to create all the needed polygons and then have the coordiends of the nodes displayed in the attribute table?

any help would be great!!

Thanks

Answer (score 15):

Not in one step:

> Vector -> Geometry tools -> Extract nodes

will give you a point layer with all nodes of the polygons

> Vector -> Geometry tools -> Extract Geometry column

on the point layer will create a new point layer with X and Y columns