# Obtaining lat/long values using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I wanted to fill in some missing lat/long values in my attribute table using QGIS 1.8. I found
[Calculating latitude and longitude of points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)
However, it seems to produce UTM figures rather than degrees even if I change my Project Properties from NAD 83 16N to WGS 84 for the exercise.

Where am I amiss?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure wether I understand your problem, but maybe try:

Layer->save as-> select CSV-> in the ogr-section layer: GEOMETRY=AS_XY

Than you should have a CSV-file with your coordinates.