# Assigning XY coordinates into multiple points in QGIS?

Tags: coordinates

I have some points without XY coordinates, and it is a global point dataset. This dataset is a 1*1 grid in a 400*800 dimension. It is quite obvious that each point has specific XY coordinates, but I don't know how can I assign a coordinate to each point? Is there any way to assign a coordinate to each single point?
My file is a CSV format and when I import this file to Qgis, because it doesn't have a coordinate I have to import it as a table (no geometry - attribute only table). I cannot edit this table.

How can I edit it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I calculate the latitude and longitude of points using QGIS?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)

Comment: Post a sample of your data.

Comment: Did it come as xlsx or csv, or some other extension? It looks more like a raster product.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  As a new user be sure to take the [Tour].  Please use the **edit** button beneath your question to revise it with any requested clarifications.  Also, please do not ask new questions as comments - we use questions for that.

Answer (score 1):

Open up the Attribute Table. Turn on editing for the layer.

Using the field calculator, calculate a new field with the following info:

Name: X

Type: Decimal Number (real)

Width: 12 Precision:2

For your expression you want:

```
$x
```

[image: calucalte X]

Repeat for Y.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but the problem is that it is a csv file and when I import this file to Qgis, the editing mode is off. I didn't explain that this is a CSV file.

Comment: Right click your layer in the table of contents and export it to a shapefile (.shp) This will make a permanent layer of your points which you can then edit and add the X Y fields to

Comment: It this is a csv file. How are you getting it to show on the map without x and y?

Comment: I tried to export it, but it shows me an error that is not valid or recognized datasource. I just import it to Qgis, but It doesn't show a map. It is just like a table file.

Comment: Ah OK, try following these steps: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html then you'll be able to export and add fields

Comment: Thanks for your reply, But my main problem is that I don't have a coordinate in my file. I mean there is no X and Y values including my file. Then how can I import a CSV file without long and lat? The only way come to my mind was to import this file as a table!