# Get every coordinate from an address database

Tags: coordinates, geocoding, google-maps-api

I have a xls database of street addresses. I want to get the latitude/longitude coordinates for all of them.

I know very little programming, but I can learn. What's the easiest way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Using ArcGIS you would load the excel data into your table of contents then right click on it and geocode the addresses (You must first have a locator) Then in your geocode options make sure to have the box checked to show X,Y coordinates.  Then run the tool and this will create a new layer which has the X,Y in the attributes

[image]

Comment: Is there an other way of doing this? I know QGIS by heart, but I don't have an ArcGIS license. I imagine there's a way of doing this with the GooogleMap API, or something else maybe?

Comment: To do it in QGIS the only way i know is to do it in 2 parts.  First convert the excel file to CSV then geocode it as shown here http://www.gislounge.com/how-to-geocode-addresses-using-qgis/  then you will  need to get xy coordinates from your points to do that follow this guide http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/get-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-a-layer or http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis