# Generate GPS coordinates for a shapefile in QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, coordinates

I have a shapefile with the network or roads (lines) of the netherlands. I also have the .dfb (attributes) .prj(projection) and .shx (index) files. In the attribute table, you can find the addresses and some other information. When selecting them, they appear as crosses (points) on the map. What I now would like to do is generate GPS coordinates for these streets in the attribute table and export these as a excel file.

I already tried vector -> geometry tools and export/add geometry columns but this just add an additional column giving the length of the road. Anybody know what else i can do or i am overlooking?

Comment: Please clarify: Do you want the coordinates of the addresses? If not, what's their role in the question?

Comment: Hi underdark. Yes i need the coordinates of the addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Kwadwo

These links might help with what you're looking for:

[Get every coordinate from an address database](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/162643/get-every-coordinate-from-an-address-database)

[Getting list of coordinates for points in layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8844/getting-list-of-coordinates-for-points-in-layer-using-qgis)