# Adding coordinates to new points in an existing point layer

Tags: qgis

I created a point layer (named PUNTI) a day ago. Today, I added a new point to the same layer but the attribute table returns me an x, y value equal to null:

Why?

How can I fix it?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

These attributes will not automatically update. It would be best to add all of the points  to the file and then use the calculate field tool for both the x and y fields.

[How do I calculate the latitude and longitude of points using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)

Answer (score 2):

Returns no value because is an attribute table, where observations are recorded by feature. If you want to add x and y on attribute table, go to *Field calculator* and update those fields with `$x` for **X** and `$y` for **Y**.

For more information, please check [Documentation](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/field_calculator.html)