# Getting latitude and longitude of lines in attribute table using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, line, latitude-longitude, pyqgis-3

I have a [road network](http://drive.google.com/drive/u/1/folders/1EbfMdSBYK5oMmP5PwxX1emqbF9TXFhOL) in form of lines. I retreived the Lat/Long using [field calculter](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/calculating-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis?noredirect=1&lq=1) in QGIS.

The method I used was:

```
long: x(centroid($geometry)), for lat y(centroid($geometry))
```

However, i want to getting the Lat/Long using PyQGIS. The PyQGIS script should automatically add the Lat/Long points in the attribut table of active layer. I tried below script but it is not working.

```
from qgis.utils import iface

feat = QgsFeature()
mc = iface.mapCanvas()
layer = mc.layer(0)
provider = layer.dataProvider()
provider.select()

while(provider.nextFeature(feat)):
    geometry = feat.geometry()
    print "X Coord %d: " %geometry.asPoint().x()
    print "Y Coord %d: " %geometry.asPoint().y()
```

Comment: Whats not working?

Comment: AttributeError:  'QgsVectorDataProvider' object has no attribute 'select'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
lyr = iface.activeLayer()
fl = ['lat','lon'] #Add these fields before executing code

with edit(lyr):
    for f in lyr.getFeatures():
        p = f.geometry().centroid().asPoint()
        _=f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexFromName(fl[0]), p.y())
        _=f.setAttribute(f.fields().indexFromName(fl[1]), p.x())
        _=lyr.updateFeature(f)
```

[image]

Comment: I am getting this eror https://ibb.co/mtcsm7Y

Comment: You have added a field called `long`, I used `lon`. So you need to change this line of code to `fl = ['lat','long']`

Comment: Yes, I added the fields in the attribute table with similar names

Comment: Yes. I did that before executing the code. Same error

Comment: Can we automatically add the fields like  ``['lat','long'] `` in the attribute table with the PyQGIS instead of manually adding?. The  ``['lat','long'] `` should be Decimal data type right?

Comment: Yes you can, and yes they should be

Comment: Thank you for your great help.