# Field calculator: Adding coordinate fields to attribute table with DECIMAL DEGREE values instead of UTM

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, fields-attributes, latitude-longitude

I have a shapefile layer with several points, each with its own ID. The attribute table just shows the IDs of these points.
Now I want to add two new fields with the coordinates (lon/lat).
I'm using QGIS 3.

Principally, this works fine by using the $x / $y expression.
The problem for me now is: These expressions return the coordinates as UTM,
e.g. 351660.879 / 5056379.192.

But I'd like to have the decimal degree equivalent!
In case of the example 13.1280 / 45.6465

Is there any option that leads the field calculator to return decimal degrees?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculating latitude and longitude of points using QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/calculating-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)

Comment: PS: look at the most recent ( >= 2018) answers - not the accepted one - in the linked post for ways of getting the coordinates without having to reproject the layer