# How to extract coordinate information of a point from QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I need to know how to get a geographic coordinate from a point, extracting it from EPSG:31982 in degrees, minutes and seconds.

Comment: Right click - copy coordinate perhaps.

Comment: Have you read the official documentation on the [`transform`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/functions_list.html?highlight=transform#transform)-expression?

Comment: Coordinates in UTM have to be deprojected to be represented in a geographic coordinate system before you can display in DMS.

Comment: Do you mean a data point in a loaded vector layer of points, or some random location clicked on the map? Where do you want to get it to? An attribute column of some data, plain text, popup on screen?

Comment: I meant a data point in a loaded vector layer of points. As a attribute column/plain text.

Answer (score 8):

You can reproject the longitude and latitude coordinates from the layer's geometry directly to create a new column for each using the QGIS field calculator.

This is explained here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/375071/110158

The field calculator dialogue for the longitude column is shown below:

[image]

That gets you to the longitude coordinate in decimal degrees. To get to degrees-minutes-seconds, as you requested, take the result from above and pass it into to_dms(). The complete field expression becomes:

```
to_dms(x(transform($geometry, layer_property(@layer, 'crs'),'EPSG:4326')), 'x', 3)
```

Or, as Matt suggested, `layer_property(@layer, 'crs')` can be shortened to `@layer_crs` making the full expression:

```
to_dms(x(transform($geometry, @layer_crs,'EPSG:4326')), 'x', 3)
```

Documentation for [to_dms](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#to-dms). This will return a **text value** so make sure you create a new text field or update an existing text field with space for the text.

Comment: Great! I was to post a similar answer, but you were faster. Nice to include `layer_property` so that you can transform without even knowing from what CRS you transform!

Comment: There is also the named variable `@layer_crs` for an even tidier expression.

Comment: @Matt, thanks for the suggestion. I did notice `@layer_crs` when looking up `to_dms()`. Edited to add the alternative expression .