# Finding northernmost/southernmost [...] point of polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinates

I have a layer with several polygons in it and would like to find out the maximal extend of each polygon in each direction, e.g. the western- and easternmost point etc.

Just tracing the polygon with the cursor and checking the coordinates seems a little imprecise.

How would I go about that?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Open the fieldcalculator and use these expressions:

`x_min($geometry)`, `x_max($geometry)`, `y_min($geometry)`, `y_max($geometry)`

---

To get the entire point geometry, not just x or y value, you can get all vertices and test whether its x or y value is maximum, like this:

```
geom_to_wkt(
 array_first(
  array_filter(
   array_foreach(
    generate_series(1,num_points($geometry)),
    point_n($geometry,@element)
   ),
  y(@element) = y_max($geometry)) -- change the filtere here depending on which point you want. E.g. to x(@element) = x_min($geometry))
 )
)
```

Comment: Sorry about being so late with a follow up question, but does somebody know how to convert the x and y values into latitude/longitude values?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/calculating-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis/375071#375071