# Getting started with QGIS plugin development?

Tags: qgis-plugins, references

I wish to develop a simple plugin for QGIS, which will open some data, and perform some specific processing.

I tried searching on the QGIS wiki, but only found this link :

http://www.qgis.org/wiki/Writing_C++_Plugins

which seems to be obsolete. There were also a few blog posts from 2006.

I also saw something about Python plugins, but I am not sure whether I need to work with the C++ plugin or a Python plugin.

Where can I find documentation, or tutorials, that would help me get started?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> This question has been converted to Community Wiki and wiki locked
>   because it is an example of a question that seeks a list of answers
>   and appears to be popular enough to protect it from closure.  It
>   should be treated as a special case and should not be viewed as the
>   type of question that is encouraged on this, or any Stack Exchange
>   site, but if you wish to contribute more content to it then feel free
>   to do so by editing this answer.

---

C++ plugins are less and less common these days. Most likely because they are more difficult to develop. Most documentation effort has been put into Python plugins. C++ still has it's place for performance critical things and functionality that is supposed to be merged into QGIS core (like new renderers for example).

There is a [**Plugin builder** plugin](http://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/pluginbuilder/) which helps to create the basic plugin structure for you.

The **[PyQGIS Cookbook](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/index.html)** offers a lot of code snippets for Python plugins

The [book **PyQGIS Programmer's Guide**](http://locatepress.com/ppg3) is another good resource.

If you get stuck, the QGIS developer [mailing list](https://qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/mailinglists.html) is there to help you.

Answer (score 8):

Basically you need to know 3 things:

1. Python : http://www.python.org/
2. PyQT (to make the user interface, if you want one) : http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro
3. Qgis API : http://doc.qgis.org/head/

They are all very well documented, to get started I recommend you to browse through the modules of the QGIS API and play with the python console doing basic things like accessing the features of a vector layer.

Later, after you get the feel of the api, you can ask more specific questions here on GIS SE e.g. [Using QGIS API and Python, to return latitude and longitude of point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/using-qgis-api-and-python-how-can-i-return-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-point)