# Which open source software to create desktop interface for Geo-processing tools?

Tags: postgis, open-source-gis, postgresql

I want to create an desktop interface to create geo-processing tool and that to using Open source GIS software. I will be using Postgresql and postgis too to save and retrieve data for operations.  I  want to save resulted geo-processing data with naming conventions in Postgresql. For that i want to know Open sources Software to create interface, geo-processing tool and how tO save and retrieve same. Is it possible?

Comment: Why don't you use QGIS and save yourself a lot of work?

Comment: I want customize the interface as in 'arc objects' and save data in postgis with versions

Comment: QGIS is open source, customize away. You can also build a stand alone app using the qgis libs

Comment: There is a PostGIS versioning plugin for QGIS which might be of interest to you.

Comment: I want to double click application icon and then directly bring data from postgis, process the data and store it again with different name in postgis. Basic motive to create separate interface from QGIS.

Answer (score 10):

Based on the comments above, as I see it, you have a couple of options.  The first is to use an existing Open Source GIS like QGIS or GRASS.  You can customise both of these by editing the source code and/or writing pulgins (the former option being more radical and the latter more akin to using Arc Objects).  Both support Python.

Your second option is to use a geospatial library and a GUI language to basically roll-you-own GIS interface.  For example, one approach would be to use Python's TKInter or wxPython as a development environment for your GUI and then use Python to interface with PostGIS.  You could do all this in .NET too.  This is the hard way and I can't see the advantage over customising QGIS or GRASS (other open source GIS packages are available).

Comment: Just to minimize the process that we have in QGIS. Directly bring the image from postgis, process the image and save back to postgis. I mentioned the arc-object to tell same as that in Arc-objects.

Comment: Why not follow this guide to build your own GIS app using QGIS as a base http://geospatialdesktop.com/2009/02/creating_a_standalone_gis_application_1/

Comment: But how i will go for geoprocessing tools operations?

Answer (score 1):

You could use [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/intro) and develop a Quantum GIS plugin. In this scenario you can reuse some code, cause QGIS have several Postgresql/PostGIS plugins ([PostGIS manager](http://planet.qgis.org/plugins/postgis_manager/), [PostGIS Topology Editor](http://planet.qgis.org/plugins/pgtopoeditor/) and [PostGIS SQL Query Editor](http://planet.qgis.org/plugins/postgisquery/)).
Good resources are available [here](http://plugins.qgis.org/), [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15967/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-develop-a-plugin-for-qgis) and [here](http://www.qgis.org/pyqgis-cookbook/plugins.html).

Answer (score -2):

I think one of the best options is to create your own GUI with Java, which is open-source. You can also take advantage of using JTS library and PostGIS for geo-processing tasks with Java.

Comment: and implement all the GIS drawing logic yourself? Not the easiest task in the world.  I would use uDig as a base if I had to build something in Java