# Where can I find documentation on QGIS C++ Plugin Development?

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, c++

Is external C++ plug-in support available for QGIS?

I'm having a really hard time getting started here. I followed the doc here: http://download.osgeo.org/qgis/doc/manual/qgis-1.1.0_coding-compilation_guide_en.pdf

But that's fairly outdated. I was able to compile and link, but the plugin isn't being brought into QGIS - so I'm wondering if that tutorial is out of date.

When I go to the wiki page at QGIS's website - they reference a VERY outdated page that is identified as obsolete: http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Writing_C++_Plugins

I can't seem to find a current tutorial that describes C++ plugin support for QGIS 1.8 (or any version close to it). I realize Python is more pervasive, but at this point we have specific needs that are supported via C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a new [Writing C++ plugins page](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/17/Writing_C++_Plugins_%5BNew%5D) though it's rather sparse. According to @underdark

> C++ plugins are not obsolete per se, but most documentation effort has
>   been put into Python plugins. C++ still has it's place for performance
>   critical things and functionality that is supposed to be merged into
>   QGIS core. – [underdark♦ Oct 20 '11 at 14:03](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/15967/what-do-i-need-to-know-to-develop-a-plugin-for-qgis#comment21077_15968)

Comment: That is REALLY lacking. I'll continue forward for now - maybe I'll update that page as I go along too. Disappointing, because Python sucks.

Comment: sir is it possible to make c++plugin that uses qgis libraries? and use that plugin wherever we want?

Answer (score 5):

Here are pretty recent examples for QGis C++ plugin development.

[QGis C++ plugin examples](https://github.com/thebigspoon/qgis_cpp_plugin_cookbook)