# QGIS export feature coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates, php

I have a big project *(whole country)* and it contains smaller features *(administrative units)*.

My project is in `.shp`.

---

**How to export features' coordinates one by one or all at once as long as all features' coordinates are separate / distinctive by eye in order to copy-paste them separately?**

I don't care how coordinates are formatted as long as I can easily copy-paste them without downloading some huge program in order to open exported file.

---

But if there's any change to control the output, my desired final format is this:

```
//             point 1                           point 2
[["lat"=>xx.xxxxx,"lng"=>yy.yyyyy],["lat"=>xx.xxxxx,"lng"=>yy.yyyyy],/*etc*/]
```

---

Otherwise I could just program a `JS` function that formats the coordinates to my desired format.

---

**All these features are on same layer:**

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on the layer you want to export and select save as and choose CSV (comma seperated value) then in the layers part of the OGR options type GEOMETRY=AS_XY

[image]

I am not sure how to export it to the exact format you want, but you can use excel to batch them into that format after the export.

also see:

[How do I calculate the latitude and longitude of points using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/7199/how-do-i-calculate-the-latitude-and-longitude-of-points-using-qgis)

and

[Using Qgis API and python, how can I return latitude and longitude of a point?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/2242/using-qgis-api-and-python-how-can-i-return-latitude-and-longitude-of-a-point)

Comment: That's the problem, all features are on **same layer**..

Comment: why is that a problem?  They should all be in the same layer, all of these methods work for pulling the x,y from a layer.

Comment: I added an image to make myself more clear.. If I use your suggestion, will I get coordinates for all these separate features on my image?

Comment: Ok so first you need to select out only the selected feature you want.  you can do this from the attribute table and the select options.  see : http://docs.qgis.org/2.0/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/query_builder.html and http://russiansphinx.blogspot.com/2014/01/qgis-basic-tutorial-1-attribute-table.html and https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZbnCrfoWnNk ... first you will select only the feature you want, then you will export only that feature out, then do what i told you above

Comment: I have problems with saving coordinates - I do everything you say but it will only save feature names and code _(basically attripute table content)_.

Comment: I forgot you are dealing with polygons.  You need to convert the polygons to points then get the x,y .  Try vector > geometry tools > extract nodes, this will give you a point layer with the nodes of the poly.  Then vector > geometry tools > extract geometry and you should get the x,y ... or you can try the other methods i showed you to get the x,y once you have that point file.

Answer (score 1):

Make the layer you want to export the active layer, and paste following code into python console (or execute as script):

```py
fn = 'E:\\test.txt'
f = open(fn, 'w')
for feat in layer.selectedFeatures():
    f.write('[')
    for p in feat.geometry().asPolygon()[0]:
        f.write('[\"lat\"=>{0:.5f}, \"lng\"=>{1:.5f}], '.format(p[0], p[1]))
    f.seek(-2, 2)
    f.write(']\n')
f.close()
```

It will write the coordinates of the outer shell of selected features to file. The output looks exactly as your desired format:

```json
[["lat"=>-0.99581, "lng"=>-0.01990], ["lat"=>-1.00838, "lng"=>0.22723], ["lat"=>-0.89319, "lng"=>0.31937], ["lat"=>-0.35707, "lng"=>0.38639], ["lat"=>-0.36126, "lng"=>-0.09738], ["lat"=>-0.95393, "lng"=>-0.21675], ["lat"=>-1.12984, "lng"=>-0.14346], ["lat"=>-0.99581, "lng"=>-0.01990]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also create a new column via Field Calculator with the following expression:

```
'["lat"=>'||$y||', "lng"=>'||$x||'],'
```

Then, export your layer in CSV format (as indicated by @ed.hankins).

Open the CSV file with a text editor such as Notepad++ in which:

- replace carriage returns by nothing in order to put all your coordinates on the same line
- add start and end brackets to the string

And this is done!